# Are the values of cin held somewhere?

Tags: c++

> Write the definition of a function named copy that reads all the
>   strings remaining to be read in standard input and displays them, one
>   on a line with no other spacing, onto standard output. Do not use loops of any kind (for, while, etc.).

I've tried something like:

```
void copy()
{
    string x;
    getline(cin, x);
    cout << x << "\n";
    if(cin){
        copy();
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

But I may not be understanding entirely what "all the string remaining to be read in standard input" means. Can someone help me out?

Comment: That code doesn't copy anything anywhere ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: sure it does; it reads a line from stdin and outputs it to stdout, then recursively calls itself if there's more to read. It's copying stdin to stdout, effectively.

Comment: @Cornstalks Oops, you're right ...

Comment: That looks right to me. "all the string remaining to be read in standard input" (as I understand it) just means to read all the values from stdin, which it looks like you're doing. But to be honest, your teacher would be the better person to ask... (also, you should probably be checking `cin` *before* you print out `x`, instead of after).

Comment: I presume it means until you hit EOF.

Comment: +1 for having a go.  Welcome to S.O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is the right idea to satisfy teacher's strange limitations however look into `std::getline` and the operators and methods of `std::cin` for correct usage if you'd like to store the input in variables etc. Currently the value read is being stored in the temporary string named `x` for each scope of the function call on stack.

**Edit:** There is nothing particularly wrong with what you have although you technically don't need the else case as the stack will unwind after last call to `copy();` and since it's a void function no return is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
void copy()
{
    { // create a scope...
        string x;
        if (getline(cin, x))
            cout << x << "\n";  // don't output 'x' when getline fails!
    } // let x go out of scope - less baggage during recursion...
    if(cin)
        copy();
}
```

The question's a bit vague...

> ...reads all the strings remaining to be read in standard input and displays them, one on a line with no other spacing, onto standard output.

Is a "string" necessary the same as a line?  One reason I suspect not is because if it is, the question's even *less* interesting (and you didn't think it possible!) - a reasonable answer:

```
std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();
```

Another reason is "no spacing"... perhaps that's referring to leading and trailing space on each line, or maybe the intention was that each space separated value be considered a string, in which case you'd need:

```
void copy()
{
    {
        string x;
        if (cin >> x);
            cout << x << "\n";
    }
    if (cin)
        copy();
}
```

Anybody's guess which is wanted....